# ng-repeat to display 6 different values in 6 different boxes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to display 6 different numbers in 6 different boxes.
My code  is as follows, I repeat the same code with required css styling 6 times but this doesn't work.
all i need is the below image

[image]

which has 3 boxes but i need 6 boxes 
'like so'

```
<button class="button button4>
    <p ng-repeat="head in data.headers">
      {{data.rows[0].measure[$index].qtext}}
    </p>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use the CSS `:nth-child()` selector for different styling on each of these boxes.

For this purpose add a class to your `<p>`

```
<button class="button button4 ng-repeat="head in data.headers">
    <p class="myColorfulBox">
      {{data.rows[0].measure[$index].qtext}}
    </p>
</button>
```

and style the boxes independently in the corresponding CSS:

```
.myColorfulBox {
// this is styling for all boxes
}

.myColorfulBox:nth-child(1) {
// this is styling for the first box
  background-color: green;
}

.myColorfulBox:nth-child(2) {
// this is styling for the first box
  background-color: blue;
}

and so on ...
```

Comment: Thank you daniel i dont have any problem with the css. When i add a measure say sum of sales the value is getting repeated in all the boxes i want to display 6 different measures in six boxes the first ng repeat should confine to first box second ng repeat to second box so on

Comment: May i should use an individual index to get the value populated in individual boxes i have 6 such different boxes to show. Can you please help me.

Comment: Oh I see. You might think of rephrasing your question. As it is missing a real problem statement anyways.

Comment: @NaiduKuchampudi I updated my response. Just move the ng-repeat one level up and you will have one button per entry

Comment: Thank you so much daniel now im able to create the objects and can able to add measures to it like sum of sales sum of order max slaray and all. Im happy buy im not able to add more than 10 measures any reason for this daniel is there anything to do with data.rows qnd $index in the measure please help me out. The moment i add the 11th measure say min salary the box appears but the value in it doesnt appear.im worried

Comment: @NaiduKuchampudi without actually seeing more of your code, there's no chance to help you on this. You should probably consider opening a new question for this :)